# Jackson XML - Is there a Java built-in type that can be used to deserialize an object containing arrays?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

Let's say my XML is :

```
<someObject>
  <someArray>
    <element>111</element>
    <element>222</element>
  </someArray>
</someObject>
```

Is there a Java built-in Type that I can use to deserialize this XML without requiring custom deserialization code?

For example, if I use a `Map<Object, Object>`, only one `element` is kept, the other one is overwritten! :

```
String xmlStr = "<someObject><someArray><element>111</element><element>222</element></someArray></someObject>";
Map<Object, Object> resultObj = getXmlMapper().readValue(xmlStr, new TypeReference<Map<Object, Object>>(){});
System.out.println(resultObj);
```

This prints :

```
{someArray={element=222}}
```

Is there any Type that Jackson understands and that can handle arrays correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case you could use

```
new TypeReference<Map<Object, List>>
```

output : {someArray=[111, 222]}.

I would much prefer to use a proper structure if there is any more complexity to your XML.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "someObject")
public static class SomeObject {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "someArray")
    List<String> someArray; 

    @Override
    // for testing
    public String toString() {
        return someArray.toString();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper map = new XmlMapper();
    String xmlStr = "<someObject><someArray><element>111</element><element>222</element></someArray></someObject>";
    SomeObject resultObj = map.readValue(xmlStr, new TypeReference<SomeObject>(){});
    System.out.println(resultObj);      
}
```

**Output**

[111, 222]

Alternatively use an array

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "someObject")
public static class SomeObject {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "someArray")
    String[] someArray; 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.asList(someArray).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This work for that particular XML, but not for any one. For example, if you add an element which is not an array in that XML, `<color>blue</color>` for example, Jackson throws an exception. I'd like something "generic" which would work for any XML. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Where do you wish to add the <color> element? I believe if you declare the structure (class) you would be able to parse the XML but probably not generically using Maps and Lists as jackson does with JSON. I read this at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#known-limitations "Tree Model is only supported in limited fashion: specifically, Java arrays and Collections can be written, but can not be read, since it is not possible to distinguish Arrays and Objects without additional information."